# Conditional modifying of rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

In my `Data`, I'm trying to change `y` to `qlogis(y)` when `dv=="B"`.

But I wonder why I get a warning message saying `NaNs produced`?

*Note that `.5` and `.6` are between 0 and 1 and shouldn't return any NaNs.*

```
library(dplyr)

Data = read.table(text=
"
id dv y
1  A  2
1  B  .5
1  C  11
2  A  4
2  B  .6
2  C  19
", h=TRUE)

mutate(Data, y = ifelse(dv=="B", qlogis(y), y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `replace` to apply only `qlogis` to subset of data and not on the full data

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
   mutate(y = replace(y, dv == "B", qlogis(y[dv == "B"])))
```

-output

```
 id dv          y
1  1  A  2.0000000
2  1  B  0.0000000
3  1  C 11.0000000
4  2  A  4.0000000
5  2  B  0.4054651
6  2  C 19.0000000
```

i.e.

```
> qlogis(2)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In qlogis(2) : NaNs produced
> qlogis(0.5)
[1] 0
```

---

The warning is related to how the `ifelse` process the output i..e all the arguments should have the same length.  Thus, `qlogis(y)` gets applied to the whole column and inside the function, it is processed so that only a subset is returned.  But, the warning already comes from the `qlogis` function resulting from `NaN` on values greater than 1. i.e. in the source code

```
...
p = log(lower_tail ? (p / (1. - p)) : ((1. - p) / p));
...
```

Thus a value greater than 1 with default case of `lower.tail` argument `TRUE`

```
> log((2/(1-2)))
[1] NaN
> log((1/(1-1)))
[1] Inf
```

```
> qlogis(1)
[1] Inf
> qlogis(0.9)
[1] 2.197225
> qlogis(1.2)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In qlogis(1.2) : NaNs produced
```

```
ifelse
function (test, yes, no) 
{
...

 ans <- test
    len <- length(ans)
    ypos <- which(test)
    npos <- which(!test)
    if (length(ypos) > 0L) 
        ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
    if (length(npos) > 0L) 
        ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
    ans
...
```

Now, we do the same steps as in the ifelse code

```
> test <- Data$dv == "B"
> ans <- test
>  len <- length(ans)
>     ypos <- which(test)
>     npos <- which(!test)
> ypos
[1] 2 5
> npos
[1] 1 3 4 6
> yes <- qlogis(Data$y)### it is the input on the whole column
Warning message:
In qlogis(Data$y) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: I get the same result as akrun with `Data %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(dv=="B", qlogis(y), y))`

Comment: @TarJae There is a warning with `ifelse/if_else/case_when` as it is related to the source code

Comment: @SimonHarmel the warning comes from `qlogis` when the input value is greater than 1.  Please see the update in the post

Comment: @SimonHarmel i.e the reason I used `replace` to subset and apply only the elements that satistify dv == 'B'.  `ifelse` applies on the whole column, and later subset the output, whereas `replace` applies on the subset and returns the subset output that satisfy the condition

Comment: @SimonHarmel Please check the solution posted

Comment: Hi Arun, do you think you might have a solution to [**this data.frame question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77208652/16762740)?